# SQL Server Change Value Of Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a simple stored procedure that is pulling data for a SS report. One of the columns uses only a letter for the value. I would like to spell out the word the letter represents for the report. The procedure looks something like this...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE RPT_MYREPORT
{
@PID     INT=1234567
}

AS BEGIN

SELECT
    SSN,
    DOB,
    PID,
    Name,
    MaritalStatus
FROM
    Customers
END
```

Obviously theres more to it but thats the basic setup. Marital Status is either an "S" for Single or "M" for Married. I would like to have these values spelled out for my report. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a lookup table to your database containing the letter and the name/description you want to display. Join your main table to this in the query supplying the data to the report.

E.g. for the lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE Marital_Status (
   marital_status_code char(1) PRIMARY KEY,
   marital_status_name char(7)
)
```

then add the lookup data

```
INSERT Marital_Status(marital_status_code, marital_status_name)
VALUES ('S', 'Single')
INSERT Marital_Status(marital_status_code, marital_status_name)
VALUES ('M', 'Married')
```

If you set the relationship between the main and lookup tables it also serves as data validation when new rows are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

- Convert value to word inside SP (`case MaritalStatus when 'S' then 'Single' when 'M' then 'Married'` for example)
- Convert value to word inside report definition (expression based on iif function)

Comment: Converting the value in the Report placeholder is probably the cleanest way to accomplish this.